# What is the best way to localize an IEnumerable?

Tags: .net-3.5, collections, c#-3.0, ienumerable, localization

What is the best way to localize a collection (IEnumerable)?
From the BL I retrieve a collection of entities which still need to localized, I figured I write a method which extends the IEnumerable and returns the localized list.

How can i get the code underneath working? Any ideas? Maybe better options?

```
public static IEnumerable Localize(this IEnumerable items, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    foreach(string item in items)
    {
        /*Error underneath, cannot assign to item*/
        item = ResourceHelper.GetString(item, cultureInfo);
    }
    return (items);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something where you [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) the item?

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Localize(this IEnumerable<string> items, CultureInfo culture)
{
    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        yield return ResourceHelper.GetString(item,culture);
    }
}
```

this won't change any other the items in the collection you are enumerating over, but it will return what you want it to.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but won't this solution recompute the localization every time you iterate over the enumerable?  Sounds like what he wants is a different enumerable collection that has been localized.

Comment: yield is C#s Ninja keyword...nice...!

Answer (score 1):

Simple change to get it to return a new enumerable collection of localized values:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Localize(this IEnumerable<string> items, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    List<string> newItems = new List<string>();
    foreach(string item in items)
    {
       newItems.Add( ResourceHelper.GetString(item, cultureInfo) );
    }
    return newItems;
}
```